# Не отправляются данные по udp с разных устройств подключенных к разным сетям. Я пробовал разные ip брал даже с 2ip

Tags: c#, сеть, udp

У меня есть приложения на телефоне и пк. Они работают если подключены к одной сети. Но если пк подключен к wifi а телефон по мобильному интернету. То пк видимо не принимает данные. Хотя там указан аргумент `IpAddress.Any`

P.S. ответ получен.

Comment: IP адрес должен быть публичным (обычно это доп. услуга у провайдера), а также должен быть проброшен порт через роутер например, ну и также фаервол не должен блокировать подключение по указанному порту.

Comment: воу спасибо, эхх я надеялся дистанционно управлять пк не вышло :) Разве что в пределах дома)

Comment: Учить, что такое NAT :) Задача решаемая, но нужно вникать в сетевую инфраструктуру. Еще можно использовать серверный вариант, когда оба приложения подключаются к серверу и через него взаимодействуют. Например как чат Телеграм

Comment: ляяя очень хорошая идея спасибо :)

Comment: Я вам больше скажу, вам даже свой сервер не нужен, можно ту же телегу использовать или любой другой подобный транспорт, да хоть базу данных Firebase, вариантов куча. Если 2 человека могут из разных сетей общаться, то и два приложения смогут, верно?